# How do i get the type attribute when adding javascript to drupal?

Tags: javascript

i'm adding javascript with

> drupal_add_js()

but drupal cuts the script attribute "text/javascript" or just forgot it. It just adds the

```
<script></script>
```

tags. Can i add the script tags? Its w3c standard...;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [`drupal_get_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/7) includes the `type` attribute (look at the source).  I suspect you have a module or theme that is implementing a [`theme_html_tag()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_html_tag/7) that is stripping the `type` out.

I suggest looking through your theme and/or base theme for this theme function.  You could also implement your own version in your theme, and put back in the `type`.

If you are using any of the modules that "cleanup" HTML output, then I would try disabling them. I have seen them do really weird things on pages.

Comment: what would be an example of re-adding or re-overwriting the type attribute with theme_html_tag() ?

Comment: Not sure if I have a working example.  Typically, I would start with the default implementation and adjust from there.

Answer (score 5):

On the off-chance that you're using an HTML5 `DOCTYPE`, you don't need to worry:

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. **The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript"**.

Emphasis mine

Source: [HTML 5.1 Nightly - 4.3 Scripting](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html)